# RMarkdown collapse output in one chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

By default RMarkdown tends to split the output. So that:

````
    ```{r, collapse = FALSE}
    print(1)
    print(2)
    ```
````

comes as:
[image]

Making `collapse = TRUE` should remove the breaks in the output but it doesn't. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the `results = "hold"` option to include all text output from the evaluated chunk together in the document.

````
```{r, results = "hold"}
print(1)
print(2)
```
````

See the [text output options](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-output) of the `knitr` package for details.

Comment: It works but only if you have `html_document` rather than `html_notebook` in the yaml header.